# zend 2: Unable to render template ... resolver could not resolve to a file

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm going through the [zend 2 getting started tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#the-database) and I hit a wall. I am at the point in the tutorial where my action controller loads a view via the indexAction():

```
public function indexAction() {
    return new ViewModel(array(
        //$albums inside index.phtml will contain data from this method
        'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll()
    ));
}
```

But when loading the page I see this error:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "album/album/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

At this point I realized I don't know what the hell is happening. I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting this error. Before I scan all of the files for typos I'd really like to understand how this error can occur.

here is my modul.config.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 
            'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'ablum' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Do you have a phtml file : `module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml` ?

Comment: Ah ha! I accidentally nested my view dir _inside_ of my src folder- duh. I just tested doing: 'album' => __DIR__ . '/../src/view', and it works so that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Provide that comment in the form of an answer if you'd like me to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error `Unable to render template "album/album/index` means that you have to add the `index.phtml` file under the `/album/album` directory under the `Album` module's `view` directory. The `index.phtml` view template file is used for rendering the view for the `index` action of the `AlbumController` controller of the `Album` module. Because this file seems to be missing, the view template resolver couldn't find it.

In Zend Framework 2, you implement a view as a *template file*, which is a file having `.phtml` extension ("phtml" stands for PHP+HTML). View templates have such a name because they usually contain HTML code mixed with PHP code snippets used for rendering the web pages. Views typically live inside of the *view* subdirectory of the module.

For beginner, I would recommend to read the [Using Zend Framework 2](http://using-zend-framework-2-book.com) book. With this e-Book, you can save your time and efforts learning ZF2.

Comment: how can I know which module is causing this error?  I added the `ZFCUser` module via composer and the site won't load .. guessing I need to somehow override the default `.phtml`

Answer (score 2):

Also, the path is case sensitive i.e. it should be all be in lowercase album/index/index both folders' name and index.phtml else phpRenderer will not be able to trace the view file and render it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved a very annoying problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if you have the following in your module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```